# How to transfer file using xmpp protocol?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xmpp

How can transfer the file one user to another.I am using  xmpp protocol for connection I have tried below code for connection. But I get message every time connection fail.

[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:@[@"testserver-desktop"]];

```
XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"256122466@testserver-desktop"];


TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:jid];

[turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];

[turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[turnSocket release];
```

// delegate
- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {

```
NSLog(@"TURN Connection succeeded!");
NSLog(@"You now have a socket that you can use to send/receive data to/from the other person.");
```

}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender {

  NSLog(@"TURN Connection failed!");

}

Please let me how to make connection between two user for file transfer.

Comment: Are you sure testserver-desktop is reachable? You may need to specify its IP address directly.

Comment: Yes Dany,testserver-desktop is reachable. You have done such type of connectivity and transfer the file,image video etc.If yes please share to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileTransfer using XmppFrameWork in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114783/filetransfer-using-xmppframework-in-ios)